# How do I change only the outer points of this point cloud to a different value?

Tags: python, matplotlib, 3d

I have a 3D point cloud with the XYZ coordinates coming from nodes on an FEA mesh. Each node also has a 4th value, which in this example is used to give it a color. Here is an image of the plotted points in `matplotlib`:

[image: Plotted point cloud]

The actual shape is easier to see when I import the point cloud into the FEA program:

| Imported Top View | Imported Bottom View |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

The blue color indicates a lower value, the red a higher value.
My problem is that the I want to change the outer surface color values only so that they will be higher and not blue. Ideally, I would like to take the highest color value of the points surrounding it, but if I could just identify the outermost points (but not the top surface and bottom surface), then that would be more than enough and I could go from there. The end result should look roughly like this:

| Target Top View | Target Bottom View |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

I've tried searching the coordinates surrounding each point and if there is a coordinate that does not contain a point I would assume it is air, and so since the point is in contact with air it's a surface point. This did not work because the points are irregularly spaced and so I would get false positives of surface points in the center of the point cloud.

I tried using `alphashape`, and creating a polygon out of the outermost points of a 2d slice and then I found the vertices of that polygon. I would then create circles at those points and if a point is in that circle, it is considered a surface point. I then iterated this process through each z layer.
This would not work because it far too long to run and it would still miss large parts of the surface and completely fill in the bottom view with red.

I've posted a minimum reproducible example and a link to the text file with the XYZC values. Thank you for any help you can give me.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NwiN5btttO0KBOR2Nuf-I8Z6sRul82WN/view?usp=sharing

```
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import sys
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

np.set_printoptions(threshold=sys.maxsize)

XYZCval = "Test Field.txt"
file = open(XYZCval, "r")
lines = file.readlines()
file.close()
XYZC_Arr = []

for line in lines:
    line = line.strip()
    line = line.strip('\t')
    sublist = line.split(",")
    sublist = [item for item in sublist if item not in ['\n', '\t']]
    XYZC_Arr.append([sublist[0], sublist[1], sublist[2], sublist[3]])

cvar = [float(i[3]) for i in XYZC_Arr]
xvar = [float(i[0]) for i in XYZC_Arr]
yvar = [float(i[1]) for i in XYZC_Arr]
zvar = [float(i[2]) for i in XYZC_Arr]

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.scatter(xvar, yvar, zvar, s=.1, c=cvar, cmap=cm.RdYlGn)
plt.show()
```